# AJAX request to a php file

Tags: php, ajax

I am having problems with a really basic request to a php file from AJAX. I am running all this stuff through XAMPP. What I'm trying to do with this code is to echo the name typed into the textbox once the submit button is clicked and the results to be posted in the div "results". I am doing this to try and weed out errors in another script and so far it hasn't gone too well.

```
<html> 


<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function go() {
var request;
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 request = new XMLHttpRequest();

 }   
     else {

     request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     var uname = document.getElementById("name").value;
     request.onreadystatechange= function() {
         if(request.readyState == 4) {

             document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response.Text;


             }


        }
        url = "win.php?name="+uname;
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send();
     }
 </script>

   </head>

 <body>
  Name:<input type="textbox"  name="jesus" id="name" />    
  <input type="button" value="Submit"  onlick="go()" />
  <div id ="result"> Result:</div>
   </body>
   </html>



<?php


  $name = $_GET['name'];
  echo $name;





  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an object called `response`, you are looking for the `responseText` property on the `request` object.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

---

Also:

1. avoid using globals
2. don't send your HTTP request before the target div exists, you run the risk of it still not existing when the response comes back
3. you probably should check that the HTTP status of the response is `200` (OK) as well as being finished (readyState 4).
4. Don't put raw user input in URLs, escape it with `encodeURIComponent` first

Comment: I have implemented most of the above changes, however it is still not working. Also would I have to use the "encodeURIComponent" in the line      "var uname = document.getElementById(encoceURIComponent("name")).value;"? 
Also would I have to decode it in the php script and how would it be done if I need to? would I be able to use the line " decodeURIComponent() " to decode it in php?

Comment: Yes, but your server side form processing library (in PHP that is the thing behind the scenes that populates `$_GET` and friends) will do that automatically so you don't need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use that
`document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response.responseText;`